# Google Drive size doesn't match

Tags: mac, google-drive

– Google Drive app on mac tells me I have 5.9 GB used

– Finder shows 6,32 GB

– Google Drive folder tells me I have 13 GB used.

If I go check what are the files that takes place, there is a lot of them that appear on shared folders that don’t even appear on my *Shared with me* Drive section.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: go to the trash folder and empty it. Do it from the drive.google.com site

Comment: I forgot to mention, but there is nothing in the trash :/

Answer (score 1):

The Google Drive client only syncs the documents and files. E-Mail and Google Photo are excluded here, but will be counted in the web interface.

Please refer to  [this picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uvPpz.png). Sorry for the non-english caption.

You may also have set up specific folders to sync only. Check out your settings [described here](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/2375083?hl=en)

You can make backups of your android phone(s apps) to Google Drive which may not appear in your drive and on your computer directly.

Comment: Yes, the numbers I gave already excluded email and photos, and I don’t have android phones(s) / app(s).

Here are the [screenshots from my interface](http://imgur.com/a/6VjMo) (now 10 vs 6.32)

Comment: Are you sure the remaining GBytes are not shared files?

Comment: From what I understand [from this source](https://support.google.com/drive/answer/6374270?hl=en) is that shared files shouldn’t take place anywhere; isn’t it right?